# laravel migration error could not find the driver mysql

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, migrate

I have php 7.4 installed in wampserver and when I try to run php artisan migrate it wont work

[image]

[image]

**config/database.php**
[image]

**env file**

[image]

Comment: Please can you show your `config/database.php` file and your `.env` file.

Comment: bro I added the config/database file ss and env ss now, can you check it plz :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that pdo_mysql is #commented in your php.ini

The php.ini resided in /pathto/wamp/php/php7.x.

Comment: I did it bro already and in phpinfo() the driver is shown :( I don't know why this happens, I am a beginner to php so this makes me disapointied :(

Comment: @KrissSachintha Did you restart the server after doing this?

Comment: yep, actually I did few days ago and still trying to figure out what solve the issue

Comment: In the past i faced many problems with Wampp/ windows, I recommand you xampp or Laragon (https://laragon.org/download/)

Comment: actually my usual software is xampp but due to the laravel not working I installed wamp and tried and also tried laragon

Answer (score 0):

did you try :

- php artisan cache:clear
- php artisan config:cache

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem,what I did was I created the table columns manually and tried to insert the data to mysql using the laravel app, then it works,I think my php artisan migrate won't work so table and columns won't create using laravel.

when I created the tables and columns manually it works.

thanks for your help :)